# Sorry, unimplemented: non-static data member initializers with C++11

Tags: android, c++, c++11, build, android-ndk

I am trying to build a library from our codebase for Android devs and am getting the error.

> sorry, unimplemented: non-static data member initializers

I know these errors come from initializing values in my class definitions, but this is all groovy in C++11 compliant compilers that I've tried.

After hunting around the web for a bit, I have added the following to Android.mk

```
APP_USE_CPP0X := true
```

... and use the compiler flag `-std=c++11`, but to no avail. Is the message actually true, i.e. is it actually not implemented in Google's arm-linux-androideabi-g++?

**EDIT 1:**

I'm using a mac with XCode installed, so I also put `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang` in Android.mk, which is currently version 5.1.

**EDIT:2**

Even with the flag above, it appears that `arm-linux-‌​androideabi-g++` is still being used for the build. How do I install a clang NDK toolchain for Android on OSX?

Comment: version of gcc compiler, using by this toolchain?

Comment: `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang` so that would be clang 5.1 on my system

Comment: Please run `ndk-build` with argument `V=1`. This will show in log the actual compile command. I don't think there may be any connection between installed XCode and NDK. The latter has its own version of **clang**, you will easily see which - from this build log.

Comment: @AlexCohn it runs this binary `/NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++`

Comment: @learnvst - the NDK comes with Clang. Look under `$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/llvm-3.2/prebuilt/`. You should see something similar to `darwin-x86_64/bin/clang`. All you should need to do is export `CC` and `CXX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang` in **Application.mk**. Note that `4.8` will most likely also work for you.